# Grails : How do I delete associated domains whenever a main domain object is deleted?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I would like to, whenever a domain is deleted, delete all **hasMany** domains and associated domains.  I have the following domain structure.

```
class Book {
    static hasMany = [ bookOptions: BookOption ]
}

class Category {
    static hasMany = [ options: Option ]
    static mapping = {
        options cascade: "all-delete-orphan"
    }
}

class Option {
    static belongsTo = [ category: Category ]
}

BookOption {
    Option option
    static belongsTo = [ book: Book, category: Category ]
}
```

I would like to delete all **options**, **bookOptions** and remove associations between **Book** and **BookOption** whenever a **Category** is deleted.

Currently with **options cascade: "all-delete-orphan"**, all **options** are deleted when a **Category** is deleted, however I encounter a referential integrity constraint violation to **BookOption**.

An option would be to manually find all **bookOptions**, iterate over the list and delete each one.

```
def bookOptions = BookOption.findAllByCategory(category)
bookOptions.each{ bookOption ->
    def book = bookOption.book
    book.removeFromBookOptions(bookOption)
    bookOption.delete(flush:true)
}

category.delete(flush:true)
```

Is there a more of a Grails way of performing this operation?  Or is the option I defined the standard?

Comment: Is there a way you can rework the domain models so the associations create a linear list of dependencies rather than circular dependencies you currently have? That would go a long way in solving this problem, simplifying unit testing, etc. From what I gather basically a `Book` has many `Option`s. Some of the `Option`s come from  `Category`s and others from `BookOption`s. So maybe `Category` and `BookOption` can be specialized forms of `Option` (aka. a sub-class).

Answer (score 1):

```
def books = Books.findAllByCategories(category)
books?.each{ book ->
 book?.categories?.clear()
 book?.bookOptions?.clear()
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I had an issue with the example domains I provided.  Book doesn't have a hasMany relationship with Category.  I updated the question.

Comment: bookoption belongsTo categories but categories has no relation back in your updated version is that correct

Comment: well I guess without that relation it has to be a little like you have it, you could look into using HQL to join up required relations as a delete statement but it still be 4 or so lines vs your already 4 or so lines. meh

Answer (score 0):

I think there should be hasMany bookOptions in Category. Please check whether the tables created are MyISM or InnoDB.